# volume control in flash

Tags: flash

I have a banner in flash. One big movie clip with lots of layers. On one layer I've dropped my sound, added a volume control that works perfectly. Before I added the volume control, once my banner was finished, so was the melody. Now it loops and loops(just the melody). Is there any kind of coding to make my melody stop once the banner is over(not with an stop btn). This is my code for the volume and melody:

```
var left:Number = controller_mc._x-100;
 var right:Number = controller_mc._x;
 var top:Number = controller_mc._y;
 var bottom:Number = controller_mc._y;

 _root.vol = 100;

 mysound = new Sound();
 mysound.attachSound("entertainerloop.wav");
 mysound.start();

 controller_mc.onPress = function()
 {
 startDrag("controller_mc",false,left,top,right,bottom);
 dragging = true;
 controller_mc.text_mc._visible = true;
 }

 controller_mc.onRelease 
 controller_mc.onReleaseOutside = function()
 {
 stopDrag();
 dragging = false;
 controller_mc.text_mc._visible = false;
 }

 controller_mc.onEnterFrame = function()
 {
 if(dragging)
 {
 var level = 100 + ( controller_mc._x - right);
 _root.vol = Math.round(level);

 if(_root.vol > 75)
 {
 _root.volume_mc.gotoAndStop(1)
 }
 if(_root.vol < 75)
 {
 _root.volume_mc.gotoAndStop(2)
 }
 if(_root.vol < 50)
 {
 _root.volume_mc.gotoAndStop(3)
 }
 if(_root.vol == 0)
 {
 _root.volume_mc.gotoAndStop(4)
 }

 mysound.setVolume(_root.vol)
 }
 mysound.onSoundComplete = function()
 {
 mysound.start();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just **remove** this (towards the end of your script):

```
mysound.onSoundComplete = function() { mysound.start(); }
```

Comment: I don't fully remember the differences between AS2 and AS3, but in addition to removing that event-callback, SoundMixer.stopAllSounds() (again... not sure it's available in AS2) could also be helpful.

Comment: `stopAllSounds()` stops the sound that is playing right now, but @Nora needed to prevent the sound from looping. Btw, there's no `SoundMixer` object in AS2.